# How do I get rid of the groups in the contact list in Empathy?

Tags: empathy

I don't want to see the groups at all in Empathy. Instead I just want to see a flat list of contacts just like I can in Adium. Is this possible?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and type:

`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Then:

`dconf-editor`

Browse according to this list:

- org

  - gnome

    - empathy

      - ui

Unpick show-groups.

[image: Dconf Editor - Empathy's page]

Comment: working solution, thanks, although I'm baffled that this is not exposed in the empathy preferences UI or so...

Comment: Agreed, that's just insane.